# After BABE changed to RRSC, explorer does not show the author

Tags: polkadot-js

[image]

After BABE changed to RRSC, explorer does not show the author

Comment: What you mean by RRSC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

This is a duplicate of a [submitted issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/8035), please ensure to only submit a single to actually save time, i.e. "calling all pockets" means it is actually less likely to be answered.

As explained in the answer above, your experience with renaming a known id into an unknown id and then not being able to extract the author is entirely expected.

Each consensus log item, be it for Babe, Aura, Pow or Nimbus has specific logic for extracting the author based on the type of information contained in the logs.

In some cases this would mean mapping an index in the logs to the session validators, in other cases it may mean using the actual log data as the public key and yet it other cases it may mean accessing a chain-specific author mapping state entry.

For anything unknown, the API doesn't try and guess intent. It works on what it can accurately map.

The JS API will only map to the known consensus ids and follow the specific logic for those to extract author information. If you decide to rename "BASE" to "RRSC" without changing logic, there is no way of knowing what you actually mean and how the author extraction is supposed to work.